# patch request spring boot

Tags: spring, patch

**Patch request changes only the data that I pass to it, the rest become null , who will tell**

```
@PatchMapping(UPDATE_ACCOUNT)
    public ResponseEntity<AccountEntity> partialUpdate(@PathVariable("accountId") Long accountId,
                                                       @RequestBody AccountDTO accountDTO) {
        AccountEntity entitySaved = accountRepository.findById(accountId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Нет такого ID"));
        entitySaved.setIik(accountDTO.getIik());
        entitySaved.setBik(accountDTO.getBik());
        entitySaved.setBank_name(accountDTO.getBank_name());
        entitySaved.setCurrency(accountDTO.getCurrency());
        final AccountEntity updateAccount = accountRepository.save(entitySaved);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updateAccount);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in the database all the fields of the model are filled, I change the first two fields through the patch request, they change the remaining two after the request are null

Comment: if `accountDTO.getBank_name() == null` and `accountDTO.getCurrency() == null` you'll override db fields. You'll need a custom save query to ignore optional fields set to null